# Error trying to run react app in docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am trying to run my react web app in docker container, building the image works just fine but running the container gives me this error:

> Starting the development server...
>
> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/App.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve './componenents/Navbar/NavBar' in 'usr/src/app/src'

As far as i know it should work but it doesn't, this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

what am i doing wrong?

NOTE: all my stuff for the web application itself including the dockerfile is in a folder called client, i changed the build context on dockerhub to make this work.

Comment: how do you start the container? Does the application work if you don't run it in docker?

Comment: @Stefano If i run it in vscode it works fine, i start the container with: docker run -p 80:3000 {reposittoryname}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i fixed it, apperantly i renamed a file on my pc, but it was not renamed on github, so that's why docker couldn't find the file